# OpenCV Developing Motion detection Software

Tags: c++, opencv

I am at the start of developing a software using OpenCV in Microsoft Visual 2010 Express. Now what I need to know before i get into coding is the procedures i have to follow.

Overview:
I want to develop software that detects simple boxing moves such as (Left punch, right punch) and outputs the results.

Now where am struggling is what approach should i take how should i tackle this development i.e.

1. Capture Video Footage and be able to extract lets say every 5th frame for processing.
2. Do i have to extract and store this frame perhaps have a REFERENCE image to subtract the capture frame from it.
3. Once i capture a frame what would be the best way to process it:

   ```
     * Threshold it, then
     * Detect the edges, then 
     * Smooth the edges using some filter, then
     * Draw some BOUNDING boxes....?
   ```

What is your view on this guys or am i missing something or are there better simpler ways...? Any suggestions...?

Any answer will be much appreciated 
Ps...its not my homework :)

Comment: Sorry to break this to you, but detecting human gestures from a video feed is not an easy task. Thresholding and a few filters just won't do it. I suggest searching for papers published on the subject in order to get a grasp for the difficulty of the problem. Also, doing this reliably under varying light conditions, etc is extremely difficult and not even mastered by the best in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if analyzing only every 5th frame will be enough, because usually punches are so fast that they could be overlooked.

I assume what you actually want to find is fast forward (towards camera) movements of fists.

In case of OpenCV I would first start off with such movements of faces, since some examples are already provided on how to do that in software package.

To detect and track faces you can use CvHaarClassifierCascade, but since this won't be fast enough for runtime detection, continue tracking such found face with Lukas-Kanade. Just pick some good-to-track points inside previously found face, remember their distance from arbitrary face middle, and at each frame update it. See this guy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNqCNMefyV8 - example of just some random points tracked with Lukas-Kanade. Note that unlike faces, fists may not be so easy to track since their surface is rather uniform, better check Lukas-Kanade demo in OpenCV.

Of course with each frame actual face will drift away, once in a while re-run CvHaarClassifierCascade and interpolate to it your currently held face position.

You should be able to do above for fists also, but that will require training classifier with pictures of fists (classifier trained with faces is already provided in OpenCV).

Now having fists/face tracked you may try observing what happens to the points - when someone punches they move rapidly in some direction, while on the fist that remains still they don't move to much. And so, when you calculate average movement of single points in recent frames, the higher the value, the bigger chance that there was a punch. Alternatively, if somehow you've managed to track them accurately, if distance between each of them increases, that means object is closer to camera - and so a likely punch.

Note that without at least knowing change of a size of the fist in picture, it might be hard to distinguish if a movement of hand was forward or backward, or if the user was faking it by moving fists left or right. You may have to come up with some specialized algorithm (maybe with trial and error) to detect that, like say, increase a number of screen color pixels in location that previously fist was found.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the research field of action recognition e.g. www.nada.kth.se/cvap/actions/ or an possible solution is e.g the STIP ( Space-time interest points) method www.di.ens.fr/~laptev/actions/ . But finally this is a tough job if you have to deal with occlusion or different point of views.